# Why is my prime number function not working?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, primes, prime-factoring

I am new to programming and I face an issue while trying to write a program in finding out prime number. Here is my code:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    else:
        for n in range (2,x-1):
            if x % n == 0:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

I received an error stating "Your function fails on is_prime(3). It returns None when it should return True."

Can someone please explain the flaw in this code?

Thank you!

Comment: Your loop is always returning `True` or `False` in the first iteration (and nothing if it has no iterations). You should only return `True` if the *whole loop* finished without finding a factor.

Answer (score 3):

`range()` has an [exclusive upper bound](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#range), so it's trying to get the range between 2 and 2 (3 - 1), which is no elements. Since you can't iterate over nothing, the for loop never runs, so `None` is returned (this is the default return type of a function if none is specified).

The solution to your immediate problem would be to use `range(2, x)` rather than `range(2, x - 1)`. You'll find that you'll have problems at x > 3 though because as @khelwood said, you're returning `True` or `False` immediately after checking the first value. Instead, only return `True` after checking **all** values in the range.

Comment: Might be worth explicitly pointing out the solution would be to use `range(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    else:
        for n in range (2,x): # range function will iterate till x-1
            if x % n == 0:
                return False
        # return true only at the end after making sure it is not divisible by any number in the middle
        return True
```